# JOIN table with max(date) where date is less than another table end_date value

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have Oracle sql query in ansi-89. I tried to rewrite it to code with JOINS.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id
JOIN (SELECT class_id, group_id, name, eff_date, 
      max(eff_date) OVER(PARTITION BY class_id, group_id) max_date FROM C) T
      on T.class_id= A.class_id AND T.group_id= A.group_id)
WHERE eff_date = max_date;
```

I this case I get records with `max(eff_date)` in `C` table, but I need to limit `C.eff_date` value with `B.end_date` value from `B` table.

I wanted to JOIN all records from C on `C.eff_date < B.end_date` and these is going to be in subquery and then select max(date) with group by or OVER(...) statement in the same way. Would it not be effective?
I have 3 more tables like C table to JOIN with same condition on date value not greater than `B.end_date`. How can I do this in proper way?

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT A.*, B.end_date, C.name, C.eff_Date,
max(C.eff_date) OVER (PARTITION BY C.class_id, C.group_id) max_date
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id
JOIN C on C.class_id = A.class_id AND C.group_id= A.group_id AND C.eff_date <= B.end_date) T
WHERE T.eff_date= T.max_date
```

EDIT:
[Link to sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/612d9b)

```
Table A
ID  B_ID    CLASS_ID    GROUP_ID
1   1        AA            BB
2   2        AA            CC


Table B
ID  SOME_VAL    END_DATE
1   value1     03-MAY-19
2   value2     05-MAY-19

Table C
CLASS_ID    GROUP_ID    NAME    EFF_DATE
AA            BB       name1    01-MAY-19
AA            BB       name2    02-MAY-19
AA            BB       name3    03-MAY-19
AA            BB       name4    04-MAY-19
AA            CC       name1    01-MAY-19
AA            CC       name2    02-MAY-19
AA            CC       name3    03-MAY-19
AA            CC       name4    04-MAY-19
```

After join I want to get:

```
A.ID    A.CLASS_ID  A.GROUP_ID B.END_DATE    NAME   EFF_DATE
1           AA          BB     03-MAY-19    name3   03-MAY-19
2           AA          CC     05-MAY-19    name4   04-MAY-19
```

Comment: remove comma between `PARTITION BY name` and `group ORDER BY name`

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I've edited the qeustion. The second query seems to be working, but I don't know is it optimal